# c++ substr in a file with spaces and break lines

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, substring, substr

I have a text file full of characters , whitespace and break lines.

Somewhere in the text file i have this :

**Your usage for this month up till now**

**Download**
**101.06 GB**

**Upload**
**18.21 GB**

**Total**
**119.27 GB**
**99%**

**Copyright ©2014**

I want to get the download upload and total numbers.
So i tried this :

```
ifstream in ("c:\\users\\admin\\desktop\\test1.txt");
std::ofstream out("c:\\users\\admin\\desktop\\test2.txt");
std::string line;


while(std::getline(in, line) && line != "Your usage for this month up till now");


while(std::getline(in, line) && line != "Copyright ©2014") {
out << line << '\n';
```

But it didn't work prolly because of the characters/whitespace/line-break found before them.

What to do ?

Comment: "...prolly because of the characters/whitespaces/breaklines found before them." Didn't you just answer your own question? Is there some reason you're not looking for lines immediately following ones starting with "Download", "Upload", and "Total" ?

Comment: hmmm how to do that XD ?

Comment: It could be that the © character does not match due to encoding mismatch reasons.  Does the first while loop work at least?  You know, you cannot come here on stackoverflow and say things like "it didn't work".  You really should tell us exactly what happened.

Comment: @MikeNakis - Oh sorry ok it returned nothing the output was blank.I made a simple text with only these content and it was working normally but gives blank if they were in that text file.

Comment: maybe your file is not plain ASCII/ANSI but has different encoding (unicode?)

Comment: Well, this works, https://ideone.com/upvTH5 so your problem is in the file that you have created.

Comment: yeah it works if there are no exceptions in the text file such as special characters/line-breaks-whitespaces. I need a code that gets me the result if whatever content is there in the text file.